# Why have a .cfg file for a program?

Tags: python, client-server, configuration-files

I apologize in advance because of my basic question, I googled it but I can not understand. I have a simple client server program in python, the server send a command to the client and receive the result from it.

My teacher asked me to make a .cfg file for it, my question is why should I do this? I mean what is the benefit of creating a .cfg file? I should run my program in `cmd` or in an IDE anyway, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server listens in a certain IP and port. A client connects to an IP and port. Any other settings you can think of about some program configuration will do.

What if you want to change those without touching the code. Maybe a user of your program wants to change the configuration and doesn't even know how to code. I bet the user knows how to edit a text file of settings.

Comment: Thank you, you mean for example I should read server IP address, from .cfg file in my client program, so in case I want to change it just change the .cfg file?  @progmatico

Comment: That's right. Configuration data should rest in configuration files not in the implementation code. I suggest you look at configparser module for read and write .ini files.

Comment: I understand, Thank you so much. @progmatico

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher just wants you to decouple the configuration from actual code. That might not make sense to you in scope of your current task. But it makes a lot of sense in a "real" project.

You maybe want to publish your code to github or something similar in your company in order to share your code or to collaborate, but your code might need some private credentials, which you don't want to share (e.g. passwords) or you have some site specific configuration. So you gonna use seperate configuration files to include this data, in that case you only need to change a configuration in order to get the code working in your context, without having to edit anything in the source code intself.

Comment: Thank you, you mean for example I should read private stuff of my code from .cfg file, right? @olisch

Comment: this always depends on the use case. You might want to have private stuff in cfg, you might want to have site specific stuff in cfg, or even business related stuff in cfg in order to keep your script as general as possible/needed. When creating a CLI tool, you want to use an argument parser instead of a cfg file, or maybe both.

Comment: I understand, Thank you so much. @olisch